# Facebook requests for {url}/no_facebook_preview_picture.jpg on 404 links

Tags: facebook, web-crawler, facebook-wall

We operate a URL shortener, over the last week or so we've started seeing lots of weird requests for `{normal url}/no_facebook_preview_picture.jpg` from Facebook owned IPs and the user agent `facebookexternalhit/1.0 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`

If I post a normal link to our site on my wall (set as `Only Me` so I can test) I get the following entry in our access log

```
66.220.152.6 - - [05/Feb/2013:16:31:36 +0000] "GET /44_U HTTP/1.1" 200 1314 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "-"
```

However if I post a link that returns 404 or 410 (spam link removed after creation) I get this

```
69.171.237.15 - - [05/Feb/2013:16:49:16 +0000] "GET /notexistURL HTTP/1.1" 404 1319 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "-"
```

then within an hour or so

```
173.252.110.113 - - [05/Feb/2013:17:15:15 +0000] "GET /notexistURL/no_facebook_preview_picture.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.0 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "-"
```

A WhoIs of that IP reports

```
NetName FACEBOOK-INC
NetHandle   NET-173-252-64-0-1
```

So they are definitely Facebook IPs.

We're getting about 10-20 requests like this a day, all identical. We can only get 7 days worth of log files back but these requests were happening 7 days ago.

I've tested links that are unique, so there is no other way for anything to find that link. I don't personally use Facebook that much, and all except my test links were created/posted by other users but I recognize all the applications linked to my Facebook account and there is nothing unusual so I don't think this is a 3rd party app (I can provide a list if needed but they're all big name apps)

During my examining of the log files, Facebook doesn't even seem to be creating these requests intelligently, it's just blindly sticking the string `/no_facebook_preview_picture.jpg` on the end of URLs, even with query strings. For example;

```
69.171.228.114 - - [05/Feb/2013:17:19:13 +0000] "GET /iAmNotARealURL1234777?ref=fb&cows_go=moo HTTP/1.1" 404 1118 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "-"
69.171.228.114 - - [05/Feb/2013:17:19:13 +0000] "GET /iamnotarealurl1234777 HTTP/1.1" 404 1118 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "-"
173.252.103.4 - - [05/Feb/2013:17:44:41 +0000] "GET /iAmNotARealURL1234777?ref=fb&cows_go=moo/no_facebook_preview_picture.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1118 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "-"
```

Google seems to display lots of random results, mostly from link originators but I couldn't find any information as to what these requests are.

What are these requests? What does Facebook need them for? Is this an error in our application or can these requests be safely ignored?

Update:

Some days we're now getting 2-3 hundred hits to these URLs

```
[sr@ns309372 nginx]$ for DAYLOG in `find ./ | grep "dftbashort.log-"`; do COUNT=`cat $DAYLOG | grep no_facebook_preview_picture | wc -l`; echo "${DAYLOG} has ${COUNT} occurences"; done
./dftbashort.log-20130201 has 0 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130130 has 2 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130129 has 2 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130128 has 2 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130202 has 378 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130207 has 222 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130205 has 257 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130209 has 178 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130131 has 2 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130203 has 266 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130206 has 667 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130204 has 12 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130127 has 4 occurences
./dftbashort.log-20130208 has 260 occurences
```

We don't provide any open-graph meta tags, and the page has no content other than a meta/javascript redirect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is the share scraper trying to build a preview of your URL, run the URL through [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and you'll see what Facebook sees / is looking for

I'm not sure what the `/notexistURL/no_facebook_preview_picture.jpg` requests are, assuming you don't have anything in your code pointing to such a URL; 
If i had to guess i'd say it was some sort of default or fallback used when there's no meta tags; possibly a bug - I'm fairly confident if you include the correct meta tags for Facebook it'll grab those and not make invalid requests, with the added benefit of the shares of your URLs looking better on Facebook.com and other sites that support the same tags

Comment: Yeah I understand Facebooks crawler, it's fine and we get lots of hits from it to expand the URLs we've shortened. Since I made this post we're now getting hundreds of requests a day for these `no_facebook_preview_picture` URLs =( https://gist.github.com/samarudge/0c4a040c389c5b339278

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing this morning and did some digging. You can use the information at [this site](http://johnliu.net/blog/2013/9/10/fixing-facebook-preview-picture-of-your-sharepoint-site.html) to help guide you in the right direction. Seems to have helped with my site getting killed by these errors.

Comment: Your "answer" pretty much consists solely of an external link. Please [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for some discussion related to these types of answers...

Comment: Hello, site owner here.  can assure people that AgentPhoenix and I are not the same person.  My blog post is specifically related to SharePoint public sites.  But some of the screenshots may be useful to people.  I agree with @Igy (upvoted) - use Facebook's Debug Tool and it'll tell you what it's looking for.  
Having good metadata for your public site is good for all search engines, search agents as well as Facebook.